# DeepPavlov ranking own responses

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, search-engine, deeppavlov

Does anybody know, how to use deeppavlov ranking module with own responses? Documentation (http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/components/neural_ranking.html) provides the following code (for insurance dataset):

```
rank_model = build_model(configs.ranking.ranking_insurance_interact, download=True)
predictor = rank_model.pipe[-1][-1]
candidates = ['auto insurance', 'life insurance', 'home insurance']
predictor.rebuild_responses(candidates)
```

But when I use this code for ubuntu dataset:

```
rank_model = build_model(configs.ranking.ranking_ubuntu_v2_bert_sep_interact, download=False)
predictor = rank_model.pipe[-1][-1]
candidates = ['environment variable', 'graphical interface', 'broken terminal']
predictor.rebuilt_responces(candidates)
```

it turns out that there is no `rebuilt_responces` method:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e013af513ae2> in <module>
      4 predictor = rank_model.pipe[-1][-1]
      5 candidates = ['environment variable', 'graphical interface', 'broken terminal']
----> 6 predictor.rebuilt_responces(candidates)

AttributeError: 'BertSepRankerPredictor' object has no attribute 'rebuilt_responces'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually replace files with data. The solution is provided in github issue: https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/issues/862